# Sign of cup product via explicit construction

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, tensor-products

Let's take $X$ a topological space with suitable properties for the following construction, and let's denote with $C_\bullet(X)$ his singular chain complex.
In order to give an explicit construction of the cup product we start with the Alexander
Whitney map which sends an $(n=p+q)$ - complex $\sigma$ to the element $$\bigoplus\limits_{p+q=n}^nC_p\otimes C_q \ni \Delta(\sigma)=\sum\limits_{p+q=n}\sigma_p^1\otimes\sigma_q^2 $$
After applying the $Hom(\bullet,R)$ functor we can take the cohomology of the cochain complex and get a map $\Delta_*:H^n(C_\bullet(X)\otimes C_\bullet(X);R)\longrightarrow H^n(X;R)$

Via the Kunneth formula for cohomology, and the isomorphism $$Hom((C_\bullet(X)\otimes C_\bullet(X))_n,R)\simeq \bigoplus\limits_{p+q=n}^n Hom((C_p(X),R)\otimes Hom((C_q(X),R)$$
we get a map that induces via restriction $H^p(X;R)\otimes H^q(X;R)\longrightarrow H^{p+q}(X;R)$ and sends $\varphi\otimes\psi$ to $\varphi\smile\psi$ which behaves like this $\varphi\smile\psi(\sigma)=\varphi(\sigma_p^1)\psi(\sigma_q^2)$

My professor added a sign $(-1)^{pq}$ and i think that would make $\smile$ a chain map, which it isn't with my construction. It looks like a long calculation, i tried to prove that it is a chain map with the sign, but i get stuck.

As a note we defined the boundry operator of a tensor product $\{C\otimes D , d^n\}$ of chain/cochain complexes $\{C^n,\delta^n\}$,$\{D^n,\delta^n\}$ as $d^n(\alpha\otimes\beta)=\delta^p\alpha\otimes\beta + (-1)^p\alpha\otimes\delta^q\beta $ where $p+q=n$ and $\alpha\otimes\beta\in\bigoplus\limits_{p+q=n}^nC_p\otimes D_q =: (C\otimes D)_n $